# AWS Batch Job stuck on RUNNABLE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, aws-batch

I am trying to create jobs with a docker image but when I run the batch job it never starts and always stays in RUNNABLE. I try to do different touches but nothing seems to work.

**discard problems**

- I know it is not because of permissions because the job definition has the necessary permissions and I have validated it with a test image.
- It doesn't seem to be the image either because when I run a container with the image it works correctly and gives the expected parameters.

All this makes me think that it is a size problem. The image is a bit heavy. According to AWS the image is around 3GB but in my local docker system it says it is 7.52GB (I don't know why).
I suspect it's because of the size of the image but I don't see much sense either. Note: before the image had a size of 11G but I was able to reduce its size a lot.

In case it can be useful, in the job definition execution role I only have the policies:

- AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
- autoscaling

I don't have Job configuration role, I don't know if that affects anything.

Comment: Common causes for RUNNABLE are documented here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html Have you ruled these out? Also are you making sure to reserve at least 32MiB for the ECS agent in your job definition memory?